# How to convert an list generated from another class

Tags: java, list, intellij-idea, arraylist

I have made this class that generates an `ArrayList()` of random integers:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomListGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Ask for an integer as user input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
        int inp = input.nextInt();

        List<Integer> arr = genRandArrOfInts(inp);
        System.out.println("Generated a list of random integers: "+arr);
    }

    public static List<Integer> genRandArrOfInts(int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n); // Create new ArrayList() of length n
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(r.nextInt(10 + 10) - 10); // We get random ints in range max = 10 and min = -10
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

When I run this class by itself, it works fine, and I get this output:

```
Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: 
10
Generated a list of random integers: [0, -1, -3, -8, -9, 1, 3, 0, 8, -1]
```

But when I tried to use it in another class and print it like so:

```
public class Lab2Array {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        randomListGenerator list = new randomListGenerator();
        System.out.println("Generated this list of random integers: "+list);
    }
}
```

The output I got was:

```
Generated this list of random integers: randomListGenerator@15aeb7ab
```

How do I convert this so that I get the `ArrayList<Integer>`? I need to use the generator in other classes as well so I wanted to make it as it's own class instead of inside the `lab2Array`-class

Comment: You need to call the actual method that creates the list: `list.genRandArrOfInts(10)` for example. If you never call the method that creates and returns a List of random integers then that will never happen on its own.

Comment: Since the method is static, you don't need to create a `randomListGenerator`.  You can call the method directly, `List<Integer> list = randomListGenerator.genRandArrOfInts(10)`.  By the way, convention is that classes start with a capital, IE `RandomListGenerator`

Comment: Class names start with uppercase letter, per Java conventions. I fixed the code in your Question.

Comment: Minor criticism: Your naming with “Arr” is confusing as it suggests a mere array, but you are using a `List` rather than an array.

Comment: Yes, I wanted an ArrayList, but the method gives me a List-object, im not sure how Ill fix it, but im working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the method that actually returns the list of ints that you want.

Also, no need to instantiate an object. Your method is `static`, so it can be called without an object.

```
public class Lab2Array {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Generated this list of random integers: "+ RandomListGenerator.genRandArrOfInts(10));
    }
}
```